# How to access checkboxes which are not yet visible on the screen in a Recycler view

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and pretty much learning as I go. Hence this query maybe very basic

I am displaying a list of checkboxes through a RecyclerViewAdapter. Some of the checkboxes are to select entire group of checkboxes. What I want to do is that if one of the group checkboxes is checked, I want to check all the checkboxes in that group.

Everything works fine till I am checking boxes which are already visible, but the moment the iterator goes beyond what is visible, I get a null return.

I have used findViewHolderForAdapterPosition and getChildAt. Both have the same issue. Is there anyway I can access boxes which are not yet visible on screen?

The relevant part of onCheckedChangedListener is given below

```
    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkChangedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        final HeaderListStructure structure = (HeaderListStructure) buttonView.getTag();
        if (isChecked) {
            if (structure != null) {
                selectedRules.add(structure);
                if (structure.type != Constants.TYPE_ITEM){
                    ArrayList<Object> temp = (ArrayList) structure.additionalInfo;
                    for (Object obj : temp){
                        int itr = (int) obj;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: Print out int" + itr);
                        RecyclerView checkbox = (RecyclerView) buttonView.getParent().getParent();

                        LinearLayout linearLay = (LinearLayout) checkbox.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(itr).itemView;
                        CompoundButton buttonToSet= (CompoundButton) linearLay.getChildAt(0);
                        buttonToSet.setChecked(true);

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
```

The Oncreate adapter code is here

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_add_mode_smart_rule, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final HeaderListStructure structure = rulesListing.get(position);
    if (structure.type  == Constants.TYPE_ITEM) {
        holder.itemView.setPadding(80, 20, 20, 20);
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white, null));
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }
    }else if(structure.type==Constants.TYPE_SUBHEADER2){
        holder.itemView.setPadding(60, 20, 20, 20);
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color, null));
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color));
        }

    } else if(structure.type==Constants.TYPE_SUBHEADER) {
        holder.itemView.setPadding(40, 20, 20, 20);
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_cyan, null));
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_cyan));
        }

    } else {
        holder.itemView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_pink, null));
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_pink));
        }
    }

    final String rule = structure.name;
    holder.cbRule.setText(rule);
    holder.cbRule.setTag(structure);
    holder.cbRule.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.cbRule.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkChangedListener);
}
```

Comment: why don't you put these 'inaccesible' checkboxes using recyclerview on screen with visibility `gone`. Gone means it wouldn't take any space but it would allow you to check if the're already checked

Comment: Thanks for the response, Piotrek. How do I do that? I am sorry, but as I said, I am learning as I go. And also how do I make them visible again when the user scrolls?

Comment: add `setVisibility(View.GONE)`  attribute to checkboxes which would be loaded, but you don't want to make them visible at this time. To make them visible you would use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know when to set them visible. I have edited the question to add the code for onCreate and OnbindviewHolder as well. What edits should I make to this? Thanks, again

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way to handle this situation. Sharing it in case someone else has a similar query in future.

For views that are not yet visible, I just marked them in the array that the adapter is using. The each element of the array has a name and type. Used type to store status of the checkbox and each time the recycler view creates the view, the status is in accordance to the value stored in type.

Thanks